# Why does my page only show black screen of background on mobile instead of mp4 video background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I tried to set the mp4 video background it's working fine on desktop but not working in mobile as it shows poster image and after poster image it displays just the black background.
Here is the video tag:

```
<div id="evercam-video-section" class="evercam-video-section">
<video class="cover-image" autobuffer autoplay loop preload id="loop-video">
    <source src="https://evercam.io/img/404.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="https://evercam.io/img/404.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="https://evercam.io/img/404.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

here is the javascript code:

```
var fade_in_videos = document.querySelectorAll('#loop-video');

for( i=0; i<fade_in_videos.length; i++ ) {
    fade_in_videos[i].addEventListener("playing", function(){
        this.className += ' is-playing';
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many (most) mobile devices do not support video autoplay to avoid the users incurring high data costs when connected on a cellular connection.

Comment: Now, it's working fine for android firefox but not for android chrome and safari ios, Is there any way to fix this (play both in ios and android chrome)? I also tried after convert video in h.264 video codec but no success.